# a PYTHON program that takes its input from a file of numbers and calculates the average

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-languages

```
def main():
    numbersFile=open("numbers.txt" , 'r')

    line=numbersFile.readline()
    total=0
    numberoflines=0

    while line != " ":
        numberoflines+=1
        total+=int(line)
        line=numbersFile.readline()
    average=total/numberoflines
    print("The average is: " , average)

main()
```

this program displays an error message-

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry im new to this, forgot to add:

Comment: this program displays an error message ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: Ok, add your question

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question and, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's in `numbers.txt`?

Comment: its randomly generated numbers from another program ex: 45\n 67\n 345\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    numbersFile=open("numbers.txt" , 'r')

    line=numbersFile.readline().rstrip()
    total=0
    numberoflines=0

    while line!='':
        numberoflines+=1
        total+=int(line.rstrip('\\n'))
        line=numbersFile.readline().rstrip()
    average=total/numberoflines
    print("The average is: " , average)

main()
```

Output:

```
The average is:  2.5
```

Answer (score 2):

`file.readline()` always returns the line with a trailing newline unless it is the end of file and the file does not end with a newline, so you should `strip` the line if you want to convert it to `int` or to compare it with `""` as a condition to end the `while` loop:

```
def main():
    numbersFile = open("numbers.txt", 'r')

    line = numbersFile.readline().strip()
    total = 0
    numberoflines = 0

    while line != "":
        numberoflines += 1
        total += int(line)
        line = numbersFile.readline().strip()
    average = total / numberoflines
    print("The average is: ", average)


main()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i ran this and got an error on line: total+=int(line)

Comment: The content of your `numbers.txt` may contain non-integers, causing `int` to raise a `ValueError`. Make sure `numbers.txt` contains only integers.

Comment: how do i do that? -brand new to this

Comment: hey @blhsing, i dont have enough reputation to move the discussion to a chat. wanted to know if youre willing to help with another slight problem another code.

Comment: Please post this as a new question since it is hard to read your code in comments.

Comment: i can only post every 90mins for some reason

Comment: I see. Unfortunately this is one of the restrictions SO places on new users. Please do wait a bit then. (Or I suppose you can register a new account if you are really in a hurry.)

Comment: just posted @blhsing, i appreciate your time